# How to print one page of a PDF using java?

Tags: java, printing, itext, java-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to print a PDF created with iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609667/how-to-print-a-pdf-created-with-itext)

I have created a PDF using iText. Now, I want to print just the first page of the PDF file. How do I do it?

Here is something that I am trying, but obviously not working.

```
AttributeSet aset = new HashAttributeSet();
aset.add(new PrinterName(PRINTER_NAME, null));

PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, aset);
PrintService service = services[0];

System.out.println(service);

PdfReader pdfReader;
pdfReader = new PdfReader(PDF_FILE);
byte[] page1 = pdfReader.getPageContent(1);

Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(page1, DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE, null);

DocPrintJob pj = service.createPrintJob();
PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

pj.print(doc, printRequestAttributeSet);
```

Comment: i respectfully disagree with George Stocker's opinion that this is a duplicate. printing just one page of a pdf using java services is different from pushing the entire pdf through the stream to the printer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't try it but [that's](http://www.java-forum.org/allgemeine-java-themen/99423-pdf-itext-drucken.html) what I found on the net in 2 minutes...

The forum is in German but the  `code` is English... should work